# Rank of a 4x3 matrix - is there a simpler method than reducing to row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem I got is:

"For which $\lambda \in R$ does the matrix

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \lambda & -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 & \lambda & 5 \\ 1 & 10 & -6 & 1\end{bmatrix} $$

have a rank equal to 3?"

My first idea was to reduce it to its row echelon form, but it gets complicated very quickly.

My question is if there's a simpler method to solve this?

Comment: Another trick is to work with column vectors. Since row rank equals column rank, and the column rank is at least 2, to get rank 3, just need to avoid the situations when other two vectors are in the span of the fist and last column vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row reduction doesn’t seem all that complicated to me provided you swap rows to avoid having to divide by terms that involve $\lambda$. Start by moving the third row to the top and then clear the rest of the first column: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&10&-6&1\\2&-1&\lambda&5\\1&\lambda&-1&2\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1&10&-6&1\\0&-21&\lambda+12&3\\0&\lambda-10&5&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The next pivot is also just an integer, so you can clear below that as usual to get $$\begin{bmatrix}1&10&-6&1\\0&-21&\lambda+12&3\\0&0&\frac1{21}(\lambda-3)(\lambda+5)&\frac17(\lambda-3)\end{bmatrix}.$$ Examining the last row will give you the conditions for the matrix to have full rank.

---

*Addendum:* Another approach is to examine the minors of the matrix. (This was in a deleted answer by HAL and suggested by Pythagoras’ comment.) If at least one of them is nonzero, the matrix has rank 3. This will involve computing up to four $3\times3$ determinants and doing some factoring. Whether or not that’s faster than row reduction really depends on the matrix and the things that you’re comfortable doing.